# 401 - Unauthorized from Azure AD with passport-azure-ad-oauth2

Tags: javascript, typescript, oauth-2.0, passport.js, passport-azure-ad

I'm trying to set up up passport with an oauth2 strategy using "passport-azure-ad-oauth2" towards Azure AD. It works fine with one tenant, but not another, even though they are set up the exact same way.

After being redirected to the Azure AD login and entering my username + password I'm redirected to the failureRedirect. If I disable the failureRedirect I'm sent to a URL that looks something like this http://localhost:3006/auth/login/azure/return?code="my token here"&session_state="my session state"

Azure issues my token, but when I'm sent to the returnURL I simply get "Unauthorized" and I never reach the callback, so not able to log out any error.

## Azure AD manifest.json

```json
{
    "id": "9c3-my-uuid",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "82b-my-uuid",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2020-07-27T10:44:50Z",
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [
        "api://82b-my-uuid"
    ],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "My company",
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2Permissions": [
        {
            "adminConsentDescription": "Allows the app to read user info",
            "adminConsentDisplayName": "Read user info",
            "id": "c39-my-uuid",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "type": "User",
            "userConsentDescription": "Allows the app to read user info",
            "userConsentDisplayName": "Read user info",
            "value": "demo.read"
        }
    ],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [],
        "accessToken": [],
        "saml2Token": []
    },
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": null,
            "endDate": "2299-12-30T23:00:00Z",
            "keyId": "e07-my-key",
            "startDate": "2020-07-27T10:57:53.945Z",
            "value": null,
            "createdOn": "2020-07-27T10:57:55.4720906Z",
            "hint": ".jq",
            "displayName": "my-displayname"
        }
    ],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [
        {
            "appId": "82b-my-uuid",
            "permissionIds": [
                "c39-my-uuid"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "publisherDomain": "my-domain.com",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:3006/auth/login/azure/return",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:3006/customer/auth/login/azure/return",
            "type": "Web"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "64a6cdd6-aab1-4aaf-94b8-3cc8405e90d0",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "14dad69e-099b-42c9-810b-d002981feec1",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": null,
    "signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null,
    "trustedCertificateSubjects": [],
    "verifiedPublisher": {
        "displayName": null,
        "verifiedPublisherId": null,
        "addedDateTime": null
    }
}
```

```js
export class UserRouter {
    public router: Router;
    private azureAdOauth2 = new AzureAdOAuth2Strategy(
        {
            clientID: process.env.AZURE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: '/auth/login/azure/return',
            tenant: process.env.AZURE_OAUTH_TENANT,
        },
        async (accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, done) => {
            const decodedToken = jwt.decode(accessToken);

            await Utils.checkLogin({ email: decodedToken.email, password: null, localUser: false, isInternal: true })
                .then(user => {
                    const permissions = Utils.populatePermission(user);

                    const token = issueJWT(user);

                    const accessObject = {
                        token,
                        user,
                        permissions,
                    };

                    return done(null, accessObject);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    return done(null, false, error);
                });
        }
    );
    constructor() {
        this.router = Router();
        this.init();
    }
    public init() {
        this.router.use(cors());
        this.router.post('/login', AuthController.login);
        this.router.get(
            '/login/azure',
            passport.authenticate(
                this.azureAdOauth2,
                { session: false, prompt: 'select_account' },
                (err, user, info) => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            )
        );
        this.router.get(
            '/login/azure/return',
            passport.authenticate(this.azureAdOauth2, {
                session: false,
                failureRedirect: `${process.env.CLIENT_UI}/login?status=failed`,
                passReqToCallback: true,
            }),
            (req: IGetUserAuthInfoRequest, res) => {
                res.cookie('my_jwt', (req.user as any).token, {
                    httpOnly: false,
                    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 3600000),
                }).redirect(process.env.CLIENT_UI + '/login?status=success');
            }
        );
        this.router.put('/forgot-password/:email/', UserController.setVerificationToken);
        this.router.put('/change-forgotten-password/:email/', UserController.changePasswordWithVerificationToken);
    }
}
const userRoutes = new UserRouter();
userRoutes.init();
export default userRoutes.router;
```

## Error

If I go to the enterprise application in Microsoft Azure Portal I can see the sign-in activity under "Sign-ins".

For each login attempt I get one successful event, and one "interrupted" with failure reason "Either multiple user identities are available for the current request or selected account is not supported for the scenario." and Sign-in error code: 16000

Comment: Been having the same problem for the last two days. It used to work fine! I'm trying to figure out what's going on but nothing so far. It seems to be something with Azure itself because I get the same error either using `passport-azure-oauth2`, `passport-azure-ad-oauth2`, and `passport-azure-ad` (both with OIDC and Bearer strategies).

Comment: @ThiagoVilla Interesting. Reach out if you ever find a solution for this. I can't see any difference between my two tenants in configuration, it seems logical that this is an MS problem.

Comment: @ThiagoVilla Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Not sure if this is a solution, but I solved the problem by figuring out that the user profile data is encoded inside the access token itself (it's a JWT). I honestly don't remember if the access token was ever opaque and now it's a JWT or if it was always a JWT and I never noticed. I used to look for a profile attribute inside the params argument in Passport's verify callback but now it's just not there anymore. Since the refresh token is just a big garbage string, the only logical explanation left is the access token.